# PL/SQL: how to convert to 'ddmmyyyy'

Tags: date, plsql

I can't seem to make the to_date/to_char (var, 'ddmmyyyy') to work. How do I get it in this format. I've tried to change the select as the output, all giving me errors.

Any help much appreciated!

```
DECLARE
auditnr NUMBER(7) := 186725;
pap_combinatie NUMBER(3) := 986;
gids VARCHAR(240) := 'G-040V.5';

begindatum date;
einddatum date;
maxeinddatum date;
operatorid number;

BEGIN
SELECT 
-- Tried: to_date(MAX(aa.datum_begin_validatie),'ddmmyyyy'),
-- Tried: to_char(MAX(aa.datum_begin_validatie),'ddmmyyyy'),

           MAX(aa.datum_begin_validatie),
           max(aa.datum_eind_validatie),
           max(aa.datum_eind_max),
           max(o.operator_id)

INTO begindatum, einddatum, maxeinddatum, operatorid
FROM autocontrole2.activiteit_audit aa,
autocontrole2.pap_operator o
WHERE aa.pap_operator_id = o.pap_operator_id
AND aa.audit_oci_id = auditnr;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(begindatum || ',' || einddatum || ',' || maxeinddatum || ',' || operatorid);

-- Tried: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_date(begindatum,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || einddatum || ',' || maxeinddatum || ',' || operatorid);

-- Tried: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(begindatum,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || einddatum || ',' || maxeinddatum || ',' || operatorid);


END;
```

Everything is giving me errors.

The OUTPUT is: 22-NOV-20,21-NOV-23,21-NOV-23,4775291
The output I want: 22112020, 21112023, 21112023, 4775291

Comment: Please be provide the exact errors you're getting. "Everything is giving me errors" is not usable. Are we supposed to guess what those errors are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert datatype DATE to VARCHAR2, use `TO_CHAR`. `TO_DATE` is used to convert a string (VARCHAR2) to a DATE.

So in your code that would become:

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(begindatum, 'DDMMYYYY')||...`